# What is the Angular4 "Change" event trigger directive in Textarea

Tags: angular, textarea

Here is one of the versions that I tried INSIDE TEXTAREA:
           (change)="dosomething($event)"

and it's not doing anything. What is the directive for "change"?

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You should be using `ngModelChange`

```
   <textarea cols="25" [ngModel]="data" (ngModelChange)="doSomething($event)"></textarea>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/cYZH61TrxtTiyNpfL84t?p=preview)**

Update:

`(change)` event will work in textarea but it is triggered on blur and text 
changed inside the text area

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/ufoEhP2DDfa7WeW8jAmn?p=preview)**

Comment: It does work with values. But how can I bind it with the $event?  Why (change) is not working?

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot

Comment: This worked. Thx.
Unfortunately there couldn't be found any further documentation about this except than that at https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax.

Comment: (input)=doSomething($event) also seems to work for me.  (I am using Angular 6.) Are they identical?   If you only want the doSomething() method running in response to the user, should you use (input) instead of (ngModelChange)    ?

Answer (score 30):

**(change)** didn't work for me neither, try **(input)** it worked perfectly :

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="mytext" (input)="autoGrow($event)"></textarea>
```